# What positions are executives, as opposed to non-executives?

Tags: position

In a software tech company, there are people who are called executives. What does that classification mean?  What positions are "executives", and what are other (non-executive) positions called?

Comment: Are you asking what non-executives are called?

Comment: If so "rank and file employees".

Comment: @Myles what does "executives" mean? What positions are distinct from executives?

Comment: I think this should be migrated to "English Language & Usage SE".

Answer (score 2):

"Executive" generally means someone operating at or near the board level -- CEO, CTO, division heads. The people who set policy for the company as a whole.

Everyone else is just an employee.

Comment: Are executives necessarily C[x]O, like CTO, CEO? Is an executive at higher position than an engineering lead, and engineering VP?

Comment: @Tim: I gave an example which isn't a Chief Officer: Division heads are often considered executive-level positions. President/VP are also executive level positions. Engineering leads generally are *not*, though there may be exceptions. The exact details vary from one company to another, so for specifics you need to ask your own employer.